# PHP remove space from a string

Tags: php, string, str-replace, spaces

I've this piece of code to rename a file by adding the uploading date, but then I want also to remove all spaces

```
rename("./uploads/" . "$directory/" . $mvcfile->FileName , "./uploads/" . "$directory/" . $data . "_" . $mvcfile->FileName);
```

I've tried with

```
str_replace (" ", "", $mvcfile->FileName);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea of why? I'm pretty new to PHP: what's "->"? Could be this the hitch?
Thanks

Comment: `->` is the object operator. It denotes an object property or method. In this case, `FileName` is a property of the object  instance `$mvcfile`.  See [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: When are you calling the `str_replace()`? You should call it before `rename()`. Your syntax is correct, and it should work..

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` returns the stripped string - it does not work directly on parameter 3 (since the function signature of str_replace does not list any parameter as a reference)

Comment: it works if I first call str_replace and then rename() it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
$data = time(); // gets the unix timestamp
rename("./uploads/$directory/" . $mvcfile->FileName , "./uploads/$directory/" . $data . "_" . str_replace(" ","",$mvcfile->FileName));
```

That's assuming what's in `$mvcfile->FileName` is just the filename, not a path.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
$mvcfile->FileName=str_replace(" ", "", $mvcfile->FileName);
```

`str_replace()` returns a string , so you should initialize your variable to it again